# Communication between ViewModels with SwiftUI and Combine (ObservableObject vs Binding)

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

This is a general question about SwiftUI and the architecture, so I'll take a simple but problematic example.

## Initial project :

I have a first `View` which displays a list of `Item`s. This list is managed by a class (which I called `ListViewModel` here). In a second view I can modify one of these `Item`s, and save these modifications with a "save" button. In a simplified version, I can do this easily using `@Binding`. Thanks SwiftUI:

```
struct ListView: View {
    @StateObject var vm = ListViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(Array(vm.data.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { index, item in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: $vm.data[index])) {
                    Text(item.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var initialItem: Item
    @State private var item: Item
    init(item: Binding<Item>) {
        _item = State(initialValue: item.wrappedValue)
        _initialItem = item
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("name", text: $item.name)
            TextField("description", text: $item.description)
            Button("save") {
                initialItem = item
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var description: String
    static var fakeItems: [Item] = [.init(name: "My item", description: "Very good"), .init(name: "An other item", description: "not so bad")]
}

class ListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: [Item] = Item.fakeItems
    func fetch() {}
    func save() {}
    func sort() {}
}
```

## Problem :

Things get more complicated when the detail / edit view gets more complex. Its number of properties increases, we must set up code that does not concern the `View` (networking, storage, etc.), possibly an FSM, so we have another `class` to manage the `DetailView` (in my example: `DetailViewModel`).

And now the communication between the two Views, which was so easy with the `@Binding` becomes complicated to set up. In our example, these two elements are not linked, so we have to set up a two-way-binding :

```
class ListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: [Item]     <-----------
    func fetch() {}                             |
    func save() {}                              |
    func sort() {}                              |
}                                               | /In Search Of Binding/
                                                |
class DetailViewModel: ObservableObject {       |
    @Published var initialItem: Item <----------
    @Published var item: Item
                                                
    init(item: Item) {
        self.initialItem = item
        self.item = item
    }
    func fetch() {}
    func save() {
        self.initialItem = item
    }
}
```

## Attempts

### 1. An array of DetailViewModels in the ListViewModel + Combine

Rather than storing an `Array` of `Item`, my `ListViewModel` could store a `[DetailViewModel]`. So during initialization it could subscribe to changes on `DetailViewModel`s :

```
class ListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: [DetailViewModel]
    var bag: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

    init(items: [Item] = Item.fakeItems) {
        data = items.map(DetailViewModel.init(item:))
        subscribeToItemsChanges()
    }
    func subscribeToItemsChanges() {
        data.enumerated().publisher
            .flatMap { (index, detailVM) in
                detailVM.$initialItem
                    .map{ (index, $0 )}
            }
            .sink { [weak self] index, newValue in
                self?.data[index].item = newValue
                self?.objectWillChange.send()
            }
            .store(in: &bag)
    }
}
```

**Results :**
Ok, that works, although it's not really a two-way-binding.
But is it really relevant that a ViewModel contains an array of other ViewModels?
a) It smells weird. b) We have an array of references (and no data types). c) we end up with that in the View:

```
List(Array(vm.data.enumerated()), id: \.1.item.id) { index, detailVM in
                NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(vm: detailVM)) {
                    Text(detailVM.item.name)
                }
            }
```

### 2. Give to DetailViewModel the reference of ListViewModel (Delegate style)

Since the `DetailViewModel` does not contain the array of `Item`s, and since the `Item` it handles no longer has a `@Binding`: we could pass the `ListViewModel` (which contains the array) to each `DetailViewModel`.

```
protocol UpdateManager {
    func update(_ item: Item, at index: Int)
}

class ListViewModel: ObservableObject, UpdateManager {
    @Published var data: [Item]
    init(items: [Item] = Item.fakeItems) {
        data = items
    }
    func update(_ item: Item, at index: Int) {
        data[index] = item
    }
}

class DetailViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var item: Item
    private var updateManager: UpdateManager
    private var index: Int
    init(item: Item, index: Int, updateManager: UpdateManager) {
        self.item = item
        self.updateManager = updateManager
        self.index = index
    }
    func fetch() {}
    func save() {
        updateManager.update(item, at: index)
    }
}
```

**Results :**
It works but : 1) It seems like an old way which doesn't quite match the style of SwiftUI. 2) We must pass the index of the Item to the DetailViewModel.

### 3. Use a closure

Rather than passing a reference to the entire `ListViewModel`, we could pass a closure (`onSave`) to the `DetailViewModel`.

```
class ListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: [Item]
    init(items: [Item] = Item.fakeItems) {
        data = items
    }
    func update(_ item: Item, at index: Int) {
        data[index] = item
    }
}

class DetailViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var item: Item
    var update: (Item) -> Void
    init(item: Item, onSave update: @escaping (Item) -> Void) {
        self.item = item
        self.update = update
    }
    func fetch() {}
    func save() {
        update(item)
    }
}
```

**Results:**
On one hand it still looks like an old approach, on the other hand it seems to match the "one view - one ViewModel" approach. If we use an FSM we could imagine sending an Event / Input.

***Variant:***
We can use Combine and pass a `PassthroughSubject` rather than a closure :

```
class ListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: [Item]
    var archivist = PassthroughSubject<(Int, Item), Never>()
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
    init(items: [Item] = Item.fakeItems) {
        data = items
        cancellable = archivist
            .sink {[weak self ]index, item in
                self?.update(item, at: index)
            }
    }
    func update(_ item: Item, at index: Int) {
        data[index] = item
    }
}

class DetailViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var item: Item
    var index: Int
    var archivist: PassthroughSubject<(Int, Item), Never>
    init(item: Item, saveWith archivist: PassthroughSubject<(Int, Item), Never>, at index: Int) {
        self.item = item
        self.archivist = archivist
        self.index = index
    }
    func fetch() {}
    func save() {
        archivist.send((index, item))
    }
}
```

## Question :

I could also have used an `@Binding` in my `ObservableObject`, or even wrapped my `Item` array in an other `ObservableObject` (and therefore have an OO in an OO). But it seems even less relevant to me.

In any case, everything seems very complicated as soon as we leave a simple Model-View architecture: where a simple `@Binding` is enough.

So I ask for your help :
What do you recommend for this kind of scenario?
What do you think is the most suitable for SwiftUI?
Can you think of a better way?

Comment: Make `@Published var data: [Item]` to `@Published var data: [DetailViewModel] and change your `DetailView` to use `@ObservedObject var item: Item`

Comment: @loremipsum : `Item` is a `struct`. Did you mean the first attempt is ok?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would like to suggest a few improvements to your architecture.

> DISCLAIMER:
> Note that the following implementation is a suggestion how to approach the Master-Detail problem. There are countless more approaches and this one is just one of severals which I would suggest.

When things become more complex, you probably would prefer a unidirectional data flow approach between your view model and view. This basically means, *no two way bindings* to the *view state*.

Unidirectional means, that your SwiftUI views deal basically with *constant* external state which they render without asking. Instead of mutating the backing variable from a two way Binding directly, views send *actions* (aka events) to the view model. The view model processes theses events and sends out a new view state taking the whole logic into account.

By the way, this unidirectional data flow is inherent to the MVVM pattern. So, when you use a View Model, you should not use two way bindings that mutate the "View State". Otherwise this would not be MVVM and using the term View Model would be incorrect or at least confusing.

The consequence is, that your views will not perform any logic, all logic is delegated to the view model.

In your Master - Detail problem, this also means, that NavigationLinks will not be directly performed by the Master View. Instead, the fact that a user has tapped the NavigationLink will be send to the view model as an action. The view model then decides, whether to show a detail view, or not, or demands to show an alert, a modal sheet, or what ever it deems necessary what the view has to render.

Likewise, if the user taps the "back" button, the view will not be immediately popped from the Navigation stack. Instead, the view model receives an action. Again, it decides what to do.

This approach lets you intercept the data flow at strategically important "locations" and let you handle the situation more easily and in a correct way.

In a Master-Detail problem, especially in your example where architectural decisions are yet to be made, there is always the question who (which component) is responsible to create a Detail View Model (if required) and which part composes the Detail View and the Detail View Model and dynamically puts this into the view system (somehow) and removes it again when done (if required).

If we make the proposition, that a View Model should create a Detail View Model, which IMHO is reasonable, and if we further assume, that a user can issue an action that eventually ends up showing a detail view and with the suggestions made before, a possible solution in SwiftUI may look as follows:

(Note, I will not use your example, but create a new one with more generic names. So, hopefully, you can see where your example maps into my example)

So, we need these parts

- a master view
- a master view model,
- a detail view
- a detail view model
- possibly additional views for decomposing several aspects and separation of concerns

**The master view:**

```
struct MasterView: View {
    let items: [MasterViewModel.Item]
    let selection: MasterViewModel.Selection?
    let selectDetail: (_ id: MasterViewModel.Item.ID) -> Void
    let unselectDetail: () -> Void

    ...
```

The master view uses a "state" which is comprised of the items it should draw in a list view. Additionally, it has two action *functions* `selectDetail` and `unselectDetail`. I am pretty sure it is clear, what these mean, but we will see later how they get used by the master view.

Additionally, we have a `Selection` property, which is an optional, and you might guess what it means: when it is not nil, it will render the detail view. If it is nil, it does not render a detail view. Pretty easy. Again, hold on where we see how it is used and what it is precisely.

When we look at the body of the master view, we implement the NavigationLink in a special form, so that we fulfil our unidirectional data flow requirement:

```
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(items, id: \.id) { element in
                NavigationLink(
                    tag: element.id,
                    selection: link()) {
                        if let selection = self.selection {
                            DetailContainerView(
                               viewModel: selection.viewModel)
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Text("\(element.name)")
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

The NavigationLink uses the "selectable destination" form, whose signature is

`init<V>(tag: V, selection: Binding<V?>, destination: () -> Destination, label: () -> Label)`

This creates a navigation link that presents the destination view when a bound selection variable equals a given tag value.

See [docs here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink/init(tag:selection:destination:label:)).

The `tag` is the unique id of the item (here `element.id`).
The `selection` parameter, which is a `Binding<Item.ID?>` is the result of the function `link()` which will be shown below:

```
    func link() -> Binding<MasterViewModel.Item.ID?> {
        Binding {
            self.selection?.id
        } set: { id in
            print("link: \(String(describing: id))")
            if let id = id {
                selectDetail(id)
            } else {
                unselectDetail()
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see, `link` returns the proper binding. However, one crucial fact you can see here is, that we do not use "two way bindings". Instead, we route the actions that would mutate the backing variable of the binding to *action* functions. These actions will eventually be performed by the view model, which we will see later.

Please note the two action functions:

`selectDetail(:)` and

`unselectDetail()`

The getter of the binding works as usual: it just returns the `id` of the item.

This above, and the implementation of the two actions are enough to make push and pop from the Navigation stack work.

Need to edit the items, or pass some data from the Detail View to the Master View?
Just use this:

`unselectDetail(mutatedItem: Item)`

and an internal `@Sate var item: Items` in the Detail View plus logic in the Detail View Controller, or let the master and detail view model communicate to each other (see below).

With these parts, the Master View is complete.

But what is this `Selection` thingy?

This value will be created by the *Master View Model*. It is defined as follows:

```
    struct Selection: Identifiable {
        var id: Item.ID
        var viewModel: DetailViewModel
    }
```

So, pretty easy. What's important to note is, that there is a *Detail View Model*. And since the Master View Model creates this "selection", it also has to create the detail view model - as our proposition has stated above.

Here, we make the assumption, that a view model has enough information at hand at the right time to create a fully configured detail (or child) view model.

**The Master View Model**

This view model has a few responsibilities. I will show the code, which should be pretty self-explanatory:

```
final class MasterViewModel: ObservableObject {

    struct ViewState {
        var items: [Item] = []
        var selection: Selection? = nil
    }

    struct Item: Identifiable {
        var id: Int
        var name: String
    }

    struct Selection: Identifiable {
        var id: Item.ID
        var viewModel: DetailViewModel
    }

    @Published private(set) var viewState: ViewState

    init(items: [Item]) {
        self.viewState = .init(items: items, selection: nil)
    }

    func selectDetail(id: Item.ID) {
        guard let item = viewState.items.first(where: { id == $0.id } ) else {
            return
        }
        let detailViewModel = DetailViewModel(
            item: .init(id: item.id,
                        name: item.name,
                        description: "description of \(item.name)",
                        image: URL(string: "a")!)
        )
        self.viewState.selection = Selection(
            id: item.id,
            viewModel: detailViewModel)
    }

    func unselectDetail() {
        self.viewState.selection = nil
    }
}
```

So, basically, it has a `ViewState`, which is precisely the "single source of truth" from the perspective of the *view* which has to just render this thing, without asking any questions.

This view state also contains the "Selection" value. Honestly, we may debate whether this is part of the view state or not, but I made it short, and put it into the view state, and thus, the view model only publishes *one* value, the View State. This makes this implementation more suitable to be refactored into a generic ..., but I don't want to distress.

Of course, the view model implements the effects of the action functions

`selectDetail(:)` and `unselect()`.

It also has to create the Detail View Model. In this example, it just fakes it.

There's not much else to do for a Master View Model.

**Detail View**

The detail view is just for demonstration and as short as possible:

```
struct DetailView: View {
    let item: DetailViewModel.Item

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("\(item.id)")
            Text("\(item.name)")
            Text("\(item.description)")
        }
    }
}
```

You may notice, that it uses a *constant* view state (`let item`).
In your example, you may want to have actions, like "save" or something that is performed by the user.

**Detail View Model**

Also, pretty simple. Here, in your problem, you may want to put more logic in which handles the user's actions.

```
final class DetailViewModel: ObservableObject {

    struct Item: Identifiable {
        var id: Int
        var name: String
        var description: String
        var image: URL
    }

    struct ViewState {
        var item: Item
    }

    @Published private(set) var viewState: ViewState


    init(item: Item) {
        self.viewState = .init(item: item)
    }

}
```

**Caution: over simplification!**

Here, in this example, the two view models don't communicate with each other. In a more practical solution, you may have more complicated things to solve, which involve communication between these view models. You would likely not implement this directly in the View Models, rather implement "Stores" which have Inputs, State, and possibly Outputs, perform their logic using finite state machines, and which can be interconnected so you have a system of "States" which eventually comprise your "AppState" which publishes its state to the view models, which in turn transform this to the view state for their views.

**Wiring up**

Here, some helper views come into play. They just help to wire up the view models with the views:

```
struct DetailContainerView: View {
    @ObservedObject private(set) var viewModel: DetailViewModel

    var body: some View {
        DetailView(item: viewModel.viewState.item)
    }
}
```

This sets up the view state, BUT ALSO separates the Detail View from the Detail View Model, since the view does not need to know anything about a view model. This makes it more easy to reuse the DetailView as a component.

```
struct MasterContainerView: View {
    @ObservedObject private(set) var viewModel: MasterViewModel

    var body: some View {
        MasterView(
            items: viewModel.viewState.items,
            selection: viewModel.viewState.selection,
            selectDetail: viewModel.selectDetail(id:),
            unselectDetail: viewModel.unselectDetail)
    }
}
```

Same here, decouple the MasterView from the MasterViewModel and setup actions and view state.

**For your playgrounds:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = MasterViewModel(items: [
        .init(id: 1, name: "John"),
        .init(id: 2, name: "Bob"),
        .init(id: 3, name: "Mary"),
    ])

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            MasterContainerView(viewModel: viewModel)
        }
        .navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}

import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Have fun! ;)

Comment: Nice answer, clear, precise, exemplified. Thanks a lot, because I think the subject is interesting :) ! Your proposal offers indeed a clear way to separate the two couples View+VM. 
And I like the idea of managing the navigation in ViewModel rather than in the View. But you put a little aside the question of the communication between the two VMs ("in this example, the 2 view models don't communicate with each other").

Comment: First, you suggest to "use this: `unselectDetail(mutatedItem: Item)`" But I don't really see how to do this with the NavigationLink, since the "selection" is a Binding<Element.ID?> : in the getter we end up with an ID.

Comment: Then, and this is interesting, you propose for more complex cases to introduce an intermediary (a Store) that would be shared by both VMs.  This will take us to the path of an `ObservableObject` inside an `ObservableObject` (and thus the need for the VMs to subscribe to its `objectWillChange` publisher). Is that right? Why the need for this intermediary? Couldn't the FSM be implemented directly in the MasterVM? And in this case we would be close to my proposition 3 : the MasterVM gives to the DetailVM its `send(: Event)` function or its `PassthroughSubject<Event, Never>` ? What do you think?

Comment: @Adrien Yes, `unselectDetail(mutatedItem: Item)` will not work - that was an oversight from me. Here, you need to extract values from the detail view model - or rely on the fact that view models communicate. Then your master view get automatically updated. A modal presented view provides a better API for a scenario where you create or modify values.

Comment: @Adrien A "store" can be a publisher emitting a "model state". It will also have Inputs (implemented as PassthroughSubjects) where actions can be connected (transformed to enum cases). In a "master store" and a "child store" setup, all events go to the master first, optionally processed, then to the child. A view model would only provide convenience functions to translate actions to events, and subscribing to the store's state, and defining a function f(modelState) which returns the view state.

Comment: @Adrien A store may also only have detail values. In that case, you only need one store, and the master and detail view models transform a detail Store.Item to their respective "OverviewItem" and "DetailItem". This is already "far away" from your views, and you may see that you can change the details how stores are implemented, possibly backed up by CoreData or Realm, or access HTTP endpoints directly.

Comment: @Adrien The decision to not implement such kind of stores into View Models is because VMs have enough with to know about the _what to render_ of the views and provide a suitable view state and setting up all actions and connect them to stores, where as Stores really deal with the data aspect, including nasty stuff like sending/handling change notifications, setting up dependencies, using/managing/purging caches, accessing HTTP endpoints, CoreData, etc.